# Script that should add 1 to a variable adds 2 instead

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I need help with a simple script but what I got adds 2 to the Variable instead of 1. Can I get some help so it's only 1?

```
var=1
while read -r LINE || [ -n "$LINE" ]; do
LINE=`echo $LINE | sed -e "s/EXTINF:-1/& tvg-chno=\"$var\"/"`
echo $LINE >> emby_iptv_tmp.m3u
var=$((var + 1))
```

This is the output I get, I want the channels to be 1,2,3,4

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-chno="2" tvg-ID="" tvg-name="AU: Fox NRL League HD" tvg-logo="" group-title="Sports",AU: Fox NRL League HD
http://.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-chno="4" tvg-ID="Ginx Esports CA" tvg-name="CA: Ginx Esports TV" tvg-logo="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/GINX_Esports_TV_Logo.png/200px-GINX_Esports_TV_Logo.png" group-title="General Streams",CA: Ginx Esports TV
http://.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-chno="6" tvg-ID="Golf Channel CA" tvg-name="CA: Golf Channel UHD" tvg-logo="http://cdn.cablefax.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/golf-logo.jpg" group-title="Sports",CA: Golf Channel UHD
http://.m3u8
```

1."Working Script"

```
#!/bin/sh
: > emby_iptv.m3u
wget "Account login" -O iptv_download.m3u
var=1
while read -r LINE || [ -n "$LINE" ]; do
LINE=`echo $LINE | sed -e "s/EXTINF:-1/& tvg-chno=\"$var\"/"`
echo $LINE >> emby_iptv_tmp.m3u
var=$((var + 1))
done < iptv_download.m3u
cp emby_iptv_tmp.m3u emby_iptv.m3u
rm emby_iptv_tmp.m3u
```

TIA

Comment: Pretty sure it does this because there are 2 Lines in the .m3u instead of 1...How to fix?

Comment: Works fine for me, after adding `done`.

Comment: But the file I'm using has 2 lines so every other line it needs to add 1 not each line.

Comment: Since you haven't posted a working script, and you haven't shown anything about what input you're giving it, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: then you should try to break it down to a minimal working example script that has the issue. (including input)

Answer (score 2):

You add 1 to `$var` for every line, but you want to do so only when it matches `EXTINF:-1`:

use something like the following to skip non-matching lines:

```
while read ...; do
    [[ "$LINE" =~ EXTINF:-1 ]] || continue
    ...
    <other commands>
done < iptv_download.m3u
```

Some additional hints:

- Instead of `cp file.tmp file` and `rm file.tmp` you can just run `mv file.tmp file`.
- Use `$(...)` instead of backticks which are considered deprecated.

Comment: Or `[[ $LINE =~ EXTINF:-1 ]]`.

Answer (score 2):

You're incrementing `var` for each iteration of the loop, so for each line in the file. If you want to increment it only for each line containing `EXTINF:-1`, you could just use AWK to process the entire file and remove the while loop:

```
awk '/#EXTINF:-1/ {gsub(/EXTINF:-1/, "& tvg-chno=\"" ++channel "\"")} 1' iptv_download.m3u > emby_iptv_tmp.m3u
```

The `channel` variable here holds the channel number and is incremented each time in that block, which is run only on lines matching `#EXTINF:-1`.

Comment: awk works perfect but just sends all the data to the terminal so I gotta figure out how to write it to a file.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff ah, yes, the increment is done in a subshell in the first example, so I removed it. But you can send the awk output to a file like in the answer (using `>`), like you did for `echo $LINE` with `>>`.

Comment: Well, the old way, the shell read a line, ran sed, opened a file for writing the output of `echo`, read a line, ran sed, opened a file ... This way, it runs awk just once for the entire file.